# Efficiently relocate elements conditionally in a panda.Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to sort the values of my data.frame in the following way:

```
for i in range(len(df.index)):
    if df.at[i, "x1"] <= df.at[i, "x2"]:
        df2.at[i, "p1"] = df.at[i, "p1"]
        df2.at[i, "x1"] = df.at[i, "x1"]
        df2.at[i, "x2"] = df.at[i, "x2"]
    else:
        df2.at[i, "p1"] = df.at[i, "p2"]
        df2.at[i, "x1"] = df.at[i, "x2"]
        df2.at[i, "x2"] = df.at[i, "x1"]
```

It is working, however it is very slow for my +40k rows. How can I do this more efficiently and more elegantly? I would prefer a solution that directly manipulates the original df, if possible.

Example data:

```
x1  p1 x2   p2
1  0.4  2  0.6
2  0.2  1  0.8
```

Desired output:

```
x1  p1 x2   p2
1  0.4  2  0.6
1  0.8  2  0.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way that use a selection of the rows and then does a swap of the values using that selection

```
check = df["x1"] > df["x2"]
df.loc[check, ["x2", "x1", "p2", "p1"]] = df.loc[check, ["x1", "x2", "p1", "p2"]].values
```

Comment: Does this keep other columns untouched?

Comment: Yes it does. It only modifies what is within the `.loc`

Comment: It gives me this error: KeyError: "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported. The following labels were missing: Index(['a_p2'], dtype='object').

Comment: Sounds like you labeled a column `"a_p2"` that isn't in your `pd.DataFrame`

Comment: Ah, it was my fault. Thank you for the quick and elegant solution! :)